# Inject a EJB into a JSF converter with JEE6

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I have a stateless EJB that acceses my database. 
I need this bean in a JSF 2 converter to retreive an entity object from the String value parameter. I'm using JEE6 with Glassfish V3.

`@EJB` annotation does not work and gets a NPE, because it's in the faces context and it has not access to the EJB context.

My question is:
Is it still possible to Inject this bean with a `@Resource` or other annotation, or a JNDI lookup, or do I need a workaround?

---

**Solution**

Do a JNDI lookup like this:

```
  try {
   ic = new InitialContext();
   myejb= (MyEJB) ic
     .lookup("java:global/xxxx/MyEJB");   
  } catch (NamingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never used JSF 2.0 (only 1.0), but chapter 5.4 of the spec says:

> [...] allow the container to inject references to 
>   container managed resources into a managed bean instance before it is made accessible to the JSF application.
>   Only  **beans** declared to be in request,
>   session, or application scope are
>   eligble for resource injection.

But so far I understand, a JNDI lookup should do the trick.

Comment: JNDI lookup doesn't work. I tried @EJB(mappedName="java:global/myProject/myEJB") where the value is the one that glassfish outputs in console as "portable JNDI name" of my EJB while deploying

Comment: don't use @EJB annotation. Get the target component using InitialContext.

Comment: @bugspy.net: still hanging in the ol' J2EE days with lot of ignorance?

Answer (score 2):

Other (yet not so pretty) solution may be using binding instead of converterId. Using JSF managed beans only:

<f:converter binding="#{app.personConverter}" />

Where appBean stands for something like: 
`@ManagedBean(name="app")
@ApplicationScoped
class AppBean {
   @EJB
   private PersonService ps;
   private Converter personConverter; 
}`

There MAY be a nicer solution in CDI-style (JSR-299) but i've *failed* to make this one running:

<f:converter binding="#{cdiBean}" />

Where cidBean ought to be:
`@Named class CdiBean implements Converter { @EJB ... }`

Fails with 'Default behavior invoked of requiring a converter-id passed in the constructor'

Anyhow first approach using binding and app scoped JSF bean **works**.

Answer (score 2):

The Seam Faces extension for JSF 2.0 and CDI allows @Inject support directly in Validators and Converters.

Check it out: http://ocpsoft.com/java/seam-faces-3-0-0-alpha2-jsf-2-0-just-got-even-easier/

Answer (score 2):

i don't know if this solution is pretty... but it does work:

```
@ManagedBean
public class AcquisitionConverter implements Converter
{
    @EJB
    private AcquisitionService service;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
    {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
<h:inputText value="#{flowController.acquisition}" converter="#{acquisitionConverter}">
```

with jsf 2.1.3 (mojarra) and glassfish 3.1.1

Comment: The `@FacesConverter` annotation is by the way superflous in this construct (and only confusing to starters). Remove it.

Comment: the converter="#{acquisitionConverter}" was the things that didnt work for me

Comment: I finally managed to get it working with `@Named @ApplicationScope` on the converter, the trick was to create an `@FacesConfig(version = FacesConfig.Version.JSF_2_3)
@ApplicationScoped ApplicationConfig` class, that triggers JSF to look for the CDI beans, otherwise it didn't work even though faces-config.xml had version=2.3