# Setter of h:selectOneMenu is not invoked

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I just tried to change a value of a select input box. Loading the page runs into my breakpoint for the getter method of the pubcategory property. Good so far. Changing the value, does NOT invoke the setter method. I trigger an Richfaces ajax processing. I confirm, that all JSF phases are walked through (I also see the JPA-SQL select queries, where I would expect an update statement for changing the value - well, can't be, if the setter method is not triggered). This is my selectOneMenu code

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="pubCategoryId" converter="#{pubCategoryConverter}" value="#{pubController.pubCategory}">                           
<f:selectItems value="#{listPubCategoryController.pubCategories}" var="category" itemLabel="#{category.name}" itemValue="#{category}" />
<a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:message for="pubCategoryId" style="color:red" />
```

My converter is invoked on both times. the getAsString method, when I load the page and the getAsObject when the on-change action is triggered. From this I concluse, the change really goes back to the server. But - again - it never triggers the setter method.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "pubCategoryConverterController")
@FacesConverter(value = "pubCategoryConverter")
//@Named 
public class PubCategoryConverter implements Converter {
@Inject
private PubCategoryRepository pubCategoryRepository;

public PubCategoryConverter() {
}

// from page to backing bean
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component,
        String value) {

    PubCategory pubCat = pubCategoryRepository.getPubCategoryById(new Long(
            value));
    return pubCat;
}

// from backing bean to page
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
    PubCategory pubCat = ((PubCategory) o);
    return pubCat.getId().toString();
}
}
```

Same story if I annotate the converter with @Named instead of @FacesConverter/@ManagedBean. Any clue or hints anyone?

Using JBoss 7.1.1, Richfaces 4.3.3, JSF 2.0

Comment: have you tried using `<f:ajax/>` instead of the `<a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" />` ?

Comment: Nope. Tried that before. Makes no difference. Same behaviour: walks through all the JSF faces, but does NOT trigger the setter method. (thanks anyway for your feedback)

Comment: do you have any messages in the server log , i mean , try adding id to that `h:message` , like this: `<h:message id="myMessageId" for="pubCategoryId" style="color:red" />` and render it with the `<f:ajax render="myMessageId"/>`

Comment: Remove `@ManagedBean(name = "pubCategoryConverterController")` annotation. `@FacesConverter` is enough and reference it as `converter="pubCategoryConverter"`. Your converter is probably failing when trying to get the selection as an object, so debug it and see what happens.

Comment: @XtremeBiker If I remove ´@ManagedBean´, the ´@Inject´ or ´@EJB´ annotation does NOT inject the beans.

Comment: I don't use EJB, but `@ManagedBean` and `@FacesConverter` annotations [are superfluous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8919591/1199132) when putting them together. You can maintain `@ManagedBean`, but you'll need to access it as `converter="#{pubCategoryConverter}"` and then remove the converter annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hooked up the phase listener and printed the `event.getFacesContext().getMessageList()`. And, there is an error although not printed to the `<h:Message for="pubCategoryId"/>`. The error is `msg j_idt18:pubFormE:pubCategoryId: Validation Error: Value is not valid`

```
package com.foo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class PhaseTracker implements PhaseListener {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.exadel.helper");

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent e) {
        List<FacesMessage> msgs = e.getFacesContext().getMessageList();
        for (FacesMessage msg : msgs) {
            logger.info("before msg " + msg.getSummary() + " :: " + msg.getDetail());
        }
        logger.info("BEFORE " + e.getPhaseId());
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent e) {
        logger.info("AFTER " + e.getPhaseId());
    }
}
```

The issue is with the `equals(Object o)` method within of the model object (some call that DTO). As stated in many forums, the values that you compare within this method must not look like e.g. this.id == o.id, because it compares instances not the inner state. Use equals instead `this.id.equals(o.id)`. Once that is fixed the error `Value is not valid` will go away.

After all, I noticed the following. If you want to use the selectOneMenu with the tag attribute `converter` instead of `<f:converter ../>`, e.g. ...

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{pubController.pubCategory}" converter="#{pubCategoryConverterController}">
```

... you need to annotate your converter also as a `@ManagedBean` instance in addition to `@FacesConverter`, e.g.

```
@ManagedBean(name="pubCategoryConverterController")
@FacesConverter(value = "pubCategoryConverter")
```

On the other hand, if you want to use `<f:converter converterId="pubCategoryConverter">` tag, you need to reference the faces converter name - NOT an instance of a managed bean. Notice, there is no EL #{...} around the converter name. However, in this case, you CANNOT inject a bean into your converter. As a consequence, in your converter bean, you need to instantiate a controller from the application context in order to use EJB services. e.g.

```
PubCategoryController pubCategoryController = ctx.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(ctx, "#{pubCategoryController}", PubCategoryController.class);
```

Comment: You should remove `@FacesConverter` annotation in order to use it like that. It's unecessary.

Comment: True. That is an improvement.

Answer (score 3):

The converter is called in the "Process Validations" phase of the [JSF lifecycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html)  whereas the setter is called later, during the "Update Model Values" phase. Each phase goes through the entire page which means a validation error in *any* component will prevent *all* model updates. If you're *not* seeing validation errors on the page try checking your message tags.

The skipping of lifecycle phases is done by calling [FacesContext.renderResponse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse%28%29). See [UIInput.executeValidate()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.7/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java#UIInput.executeValidate%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) and [LifeCycleImpl.execute()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.1.7/com/sun/faces/lifecycle/LifecycleImpl.java#LifecycleImpl.execute%28com.sun.faces.lifecycle.FacesContext%29) for details.